# Using TCP RESET counts from upstream servers in proxy_next_upstream to mark them down

Tags: nginx, load-balancing

We are using nginx to front-end our apache connections with good results. I am now toying with the idea of also using nginx (a separate instance) to load balance some of the back-end services. In order to be able to do that I want to understand nginx proxy_next_upstream module behavior better.

`syntax: proxy_next_upstream error | timeout | invalid_header | http_500 | http_502 | http_503 | http_504 | http_404 | off ...;`

`default:proxy_next_upstream error timeout;`

`context: http, server, location`

Can I specifically use TCP RST as one of the parameters in there to mark down a load balanced server? What all does really 1st parameter i.e. "error" encapsulate? Can I add my errors (RSTs etc)? I have tried some ways of setting RSTs in there but that does not seem to work.

Comment: Something of this nature is already supported by CITRIX Netscaler. One can set up probes on and mark a virtual (server) down after a probe SYN packet encounters a RST packet in response from load balanced server for "N" consecutive times (default is 3, I think)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://nginx.org/r/proxy_next_upstream

> error — an error occurred while establishing a connection with the server, passing it a request, or reading the response header;

This must handle RST on SYN too.

Comment: Hello VBart. I saw this documentation earlier and I will accept your answer because my logic was also similar. But I also wanted to know if someone has used something similar with nginx upstream module and if there are some learning from there.